# Замена функции eregi_replace в новой версии PHP

Tags: php, php7

Есть переменные с функцией eregi_replace, с сожалению функция давно устарела. Подскажите пример как на php 7 то же самое сделать.

```html
$php=eregi_replace('[^-a-zа-я0-9 !\?\.\,]',' ',$str);
$php=eregi_replace(' {1,}([!\?\.\,])','\\1',$str);
```

Comment: `preg_replace()`?

Comment: с модификатором i